# ( session: options?.session, ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.')mongoose give a error deploying in instance ubuntu aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mongoose, syntax-error

I have this error while using mongoose:

```
/var/www/node-api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:62
            session: options?.session,
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

I reinstalled node_modules but I always get the same problem.

For mongoose and my connection in my device it worked correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an answer for this because it keeps coming up.

**Problem:**

Mongoose uses the MongoDB native Node.js driver as one of it's dependencies.

In the [mongodb V6 native driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb/v/6.0.0?activeTab=code) they implemented [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in the `async command()` within `admin.js`:

```js
async command(command, options) {
   return (0, execute_operation_1.executeOperation)(this.s.db.client, new run_command_1.RunAdminCommandOperation(command, {
      ...(0, bson_1.resolveBSONOptions)(options),
      session: options?.session, //< optional chaining here
      readPreference: options?.readPreference
   }));
}
```

The problem is that [optional chaining wasn't supported in Node.js until V14.5](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----).

**Solution**:

You need to upgrade your Node.js version to a newer version. At the current time of writing, Node V20 is the LTS so I would recommend upgrading to that or see the [Release Schedule](https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases#release-schedule) to plan ahead.